# How can I ignore dockerfile non-zero return codes?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm working on a dockerfile for the meganz cmd utility.

I have set environment variables for the login command and it works as intended on my private builds, with a legit username and password.

I am making a public build using dockerhub and I populate the environment variables with default values and it causes the automatic build to fail in DockerHub.

Is it possible to ignore this specific error during the build so it passes? I fully expect this command to fail with default credentials.

`RUN mega-login ${email} ${password}`

`The command '/bin/sh -c mega-login ${email} ${password}' returned a non-zero code: 13`

Comment: Anyone who gets the image later on can very easily retrieve these credentials; you almost certainly don't want to run this command as part of the image build.  I'd delete this `RUN` line entirely, and if the parameters are set up with `ARG`, delete those too.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on different ways to pass in credentials through compose? That would be more secure. I've worked with a few containers that pass in the password as an environment variable, which is what I'm doing here.  I think ideally I want it to be a secret? But this is my first container build, so I'm working bit by bit

Comment: An environment variable would be typical.  If you need to run this login step as part of your container startup (it needs to run with runtime environment variables, but before the main container process can go) an entrypoint wrapper script can set this up.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!
It would need to run once the container starts, not as part of the build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `||` to bypass the exit code. Something like next:

**Old Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN lll
RUN pwd
```

**Old execution:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 065cf14a189c
Step 2/3 : RUN lll
 ---> Running in b7f9a2fd7f6d
/bin/sh: 1: lll: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c lll' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

**New Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN lll || :
RUN pwd
```

**New execution:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 065cf14a189c
Step 2/3 : RUN lll || :
 ---> Running in 9a0b3ebea003
/bin/sh: 1: lll: not found
Removing intermediate container 9a0b3ebea003
 ---> af76014cf9aa
Step 3/3 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in a4766055c81e
/
Removing intermediate container a4766055c81e
 ---> c82c077ed8ea
Successfully built c82c077ed8ea
Successfully tagged abc:1
```

**Explain for `cmd1 || cmd2`:**

If `cmd1` exit code is zero, the `cmd2` will not execute, if `cmd1` exit code is non-zero, the `cmd2` will run. Here, `:` means a empty command which will result in zero exit code, then it will cheat docker build to let it not exit.

So, for you it could be:

```
RUN mega-login ${email} ${password} || :
```

Comment: Perfect answer to the question!

I will re-work how I am attempting to accomplish this login though.